# htaccess redirect on index file when try to access dir

Tags: perl, apache, .htaccess

Trying to deny access to all files except index.pl. First I deny all, after that allow access to index.pl. Next code works properly.

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
<Files "index.pl">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

But after adding .htaccess file with this content appeared the following issue:
When I try to access *mysite.com/* (without index.pl) server says it's forbidden.

I tried to add `DirectoryIndex index.pl`, code has become so:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
<Files "index.pl">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Files>

DirectoryIndex index.pl
```

It didn't help me.

What I have to write in file to restrict all files except index.pl and site would work properly without adding `/index.pl` to link?  Maybe there are another method to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mod_rewrite` rule for finer control. Try this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!(index|search)\.pl).+$ - [F,NC]
```

Comment: hm :) thank you ! it works. Now searching how to access .css and .js files too :). Btw, interesting mod :) Going to read more about it and make link more beautiful :) ty

Comment: Thank you! Your code works! Just 1 moment. I just added search function to my site and it's using search.pl file from root dir. How I have to update code to allow access to this file too?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your `<Files>` block to a `<FilesMatch>` and make the `index.pl` optional:

```
<FilesMatch "^(index.pl)?$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you mean just putting ONLY THIS code into .htaccess? I just tried and it hadn't worked for me.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav No, replace your `<Files "index.pl"> ... </Files>` block with the above, you still need everything else.

Comment: I just copy pasted your code, I deleted content of my .htaccess, I pasted your code into. That's all. It didn't help me

Comment: @SharikovVladislav **don't delete all your code**, just replace the `<Files>` part, you still need the rest of your code for it to work. You just need to replace those 4 lines with the 4 lines above.

Comment: Oops! Really! My bad, sorry! Your code working too! Thanks for your answer.